# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementiation()' Possible causes:

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to use firebase with my App and i did all the steps listed in the official website of firebase on how to add the google-service plugin and the firebase products into both my module and project build.gradle , but i still got this list of errors :

> ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementiation()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> 1-The project 'FriendlyChat' may be using a version of the Android
>   Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile'
>   was added in 1.1.0).
>
> 2-The project 'FriendlyChat' may be using a version of Gradle that
>   does not contain the method.
>
> 3-The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

and i referred to the possible solutions here on stackoverflow but i got the same results.

here's my project:buidl.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here's my app:build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementiation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha05'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha05'

}
```

Comment: It is a simple **typo**. `implementiation` instead of `implementation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo in your `build.gradle`. You have used **implementiation** instead of **implementation**.

Change this like below:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.4'
```

instead of

```
implementiation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.4'
```

Comment: @linasaeed, Have you checked this?

Comment: yes i did , it worked thanks , but i got other errors :ERROR: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 12 path $

Comment: Where is `firebase-database`? I didn't find it

Comment: i add it later   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'

Comment: That is different issue. Please ask this problem in another thread to keep this simple. It's recommended in **SO** to ask single question in a thread. Hope you understand.